# Arquillian Java deployment with dependent Scala classes will not load

Tags: java, scala, jboss-arquillian

I have an Arquillian deployment but the archive will not load due to Scala dependencies.

The issue I have isolated is that scala.util.Random getSimpleName() results in a malformed class name at runtime.

Hence the deployment can never start.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I have never used Scala, so I cannot help you so much, but I remember there was this example https://github.com/kazuhira-r/javaee7-scala-examples/tree/master/arquillian-getting-started which maybe you can use as a reference example.

Answer (score 0):

Above is not possible. Instead I have set up an Embedded ZK/Kafka cluster, which I load through a separate JVM process using Arquillian SPI.

I CAN use the client code in my tests to connect to the embedded ZK/Kafka using the regular localhost:9092 port.